# WebClient throws 404 on url - spring boot

Tags: java, spring, webclient

I have just started to work with `webclient` and I am not aware of full scope of its usage.

So i tried creating a `GET` request with a `HttpURLConnection` object which works perfectly.
Below is the code:

```
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    String authHeaderValue;
    authHeaderValue = getAuthorizationHeader();
    BufferedReader reader;
    String line;
    StringBuilder responseConstant = new StringBuilder();
    URL url = new URL(complete_url);

    System.out.println(url);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("??","??");
    connection.setRequestProperty("??",??);
    connection.setRequestProperty("??",??);
    connection.setRequestProperty("??","??");
    connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

    if (responseCode > 299) {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
    } else {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    }
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        responseConstant.append(line);
    }
    reader.close();

    return responseConstant;
```

But similar implementation for a webclient object says that `404 Not Found from GET` https://advertising-api-eu.amazon.com/v2/profiles

Below is the implementation:

```
WebClient newWebClient = WebClient
            .builder()
            .baseUrl("https://advertising-api-eu.amazon.com")
            .defaultHeader(??,??)
            .defaultHeader(??,??)
            .defaultHeader(??,??)
            .defaultHeader(??,??)
            .build();

    return newWebClient
            .method(HttpMethod.GET)
            .uri("/v2/profiles")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);
```

Could anyone please tell if there is some restrictions towards the usage of `webclient` or is there some error in my code.

Comment: What is the value of `complete_url` in your first code block?

Comment: It is "https://advertising-api-eu.amazon.com/v2/profiles" same as the webclient.